# Update using "with" clause mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm coming from SQL Server and Oracle. Can't deal much with Mysql but here we are.
How can i update two fields from this query?

```
with p1 as(
SELECT * FROM FIRST_TABLE
), p2 as(
SELECT * FROM SECOND_TABLE
), p3 as(
SELECT * FROM THIRD_TABLE
) 
SELECT * FROM P3
```

I just simplified the query. I tried merge and update and none of them working with this structure.

EDIT: That's my query

```
with p1 as(
SELECT C.produzione, C.vcf_3_1, C.cid, G.changelogid, G.modified_date as start, G.description FROM vte_cartellinoproduzione C JOIN vte_changelog G on C.cid = G.parent_id 
), p2 as(
SELECT C.produzione, C.vcf_3_1, C.cid, G.changelogid, G.modified_date as end, G.description FROM vte_cartellinoproduzione C JOIN vte_changelog G on C.cid = G.parent_id
), p3 as(
SELECT p1.cid, p1.vcf_3_1 as nome, p1.produzione, DATEDIFF(end,start) as giorni_totali, 5 * (DATEDIFF(end, start) DIV 7) + MID('0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450', 7 * WEEKDAY(start) + WEEKDAY(end) + 1, 1) as giorni_produzione
 FROM p1 JOIN p2 on p1.cid = p2.cid
), p4 as(
SELECT nome, produzione, cid, min(giorni_produzione) as giorni_produzione, min(giorni_totali) as giorni_totali
FROM p3 where giorni_produzione > 0 GROUP BY nome, produzione, cid
)
UPDATE produzionecf 
SET cf_hm2_1601 = p4.giorni_totali, cf_hm2_1602 = p4.giorni_produzione
FROM produzionecf cf 
JOIN p4
on p4.cid = cf.cid;
```

MYSQL tell me syntax error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ') UPDATE produzionecf SET
> cf_hm2_1601 = p4.giorni_totali, cf_hm2_' at line 1

I tried also ( i report only the update part) but not working too

```
UPDATE produzionecf 
SET cf_hm2_1601 = p4.giorni_totali, cf_hm2_1602 = p4.giorni_produzione
WHERE cid = (SELECT cid FROM P4);
```

and

```
UPDATE produzionecf 
SET cf_hm2_1601 = p4.giorni_totali, cf_hm2_1602 = p4.giorni_produzione
WHERE cid = p4.cid
```

**EDIT 2 SOLVED**

Akina solution (in the comment) worked. I have used also https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ to validate the query. I had a semicolom somewhere.

```
UPDATE produzionecf JOIN p4 on p4.cid = cf.cid SET cf_hm2_1601 = p4.giorni_totali, cf_hm2_1602 = p4.giorni_produzione
```

Comment: SELECT cannot update anything, it only selects.

Comment: How to use WITH in UPDATE - [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4c5f1900ae24f976848e9c7db766438)

Comment: I put the entire query so you can understand better my problem.

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) - study carefully, especially "Multiple-table syntax". There is no FROM clause in it.

Comment: ```... UPDATE produzionecf JOIN p4 on p4.cid = cf.cid SET cf_hm2_1601 = p4.giorni_totali, cf_hm2_1602 = p4.giorni_produzione;```

Comment: Do not exists UPDATE .. FROM in MySql. It's a facility of Sql Server